# Hibernate: how to handle 'saving' a transient object that may or may not exist in the database

Tags: hibernate, transient

this is a Hibernate question about persisting transient objects that may already exist in my database.

Given a transient object (Id is null) that may or may not already exist in my database, and that also has a unique column (ie my business primary key, which is annotated with 'unique=true').  How do I attempt to save it without the risk of getting the error: **integrity constraint violation: unique constraint or index violation**

Should I be providing the methods to check the database for duplicates before trying to persist the object?  Which is a bit frustrating.

Here is the test I perform to try to save two identical transient objects...

Here is my object:

```
@Entity
public class ArchivedLicence extends DomainObject implements Licence {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 84973741L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    @Column (unique=true, nullable=false)
    private String md5Hash;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o instanceof ArchivedLicence) {
            return md5Hash.equals(((ArchivedLicence)o).md5Hash);
        }
        return super.equals(o);
    }
    ...
```

Here is the save method in my Data Access Object:

```
    @Transactional
    @Override
    public void saveOrUpdate(ArchivedLicence archivedLicence) {

        getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(archivedLicence);
        //getCurrentSession().save(archivedLicence);
    }
```

Here is my test:

```
        //Given the first ArchivedLicence
        ArchivedLicence archivedLicence1 = null;
        try {
            archivedLicence1 = new ArchivedLicence(licenceDao.getByName(internalLicenceName));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OrderTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        //When it is persisted
        archivedLicenceDao.saveOrUpdate(archivedLicence1);
        flush();

        //Then there should be one ArchivedLicence in the the database
        assertEquals(new Long(1), archivedLicenceDao.countAll());

        //When a second identical ArchiviedLicence is persisted
        ArchivedLicence archivedLicence2 = null;
        try {
            archivedLicence2 = new ArchivedLicence(licenceDao.getByName(internalLicenceName));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(OrderTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        archivedLicenceDao.saveOrUpdate(archivedLicence2);
        flush();

        //Then there should still only be one ArchivedLicence in the database
        assertEquals(new Long(1), archivedLicenceDao.countAll());
```

Any help appreciated, thanks, Jon

Comment: Could you just perform the save and flush and catch the exception?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you're going to have to query the database to see if the object exists, and then update it if it does, and save a new object if it does not.

saveOrUpdate is not for this purpose - what it does is to check the id of the object in memory, and then call save if the id is null, update if the id is not null.